# Cedet autocomplete constructors in cpp project

Tags: c++, autocomplete, constructor, cedet

I would like to know if there is a possible way to configure `auto-complete` and `Cedet` in order to get constructors completion.

I have searched on Internet, and the only reference I got is

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.cedet/4391.

I have used Alex's tutorial http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html to configure my CEDET.

Am I missing something?